# Why does the following summation equivalence hold true?

Tags: summation, gauss-sums

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i}^{n}(j-i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j^{\prime}=0}^{n-i} j^{\prime}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j^{\prime}=1}^{n-i} j^{\prime}
$$

Can someone explain to me how we got from the first to the second double summation?

Comment: Just set $j'=j-i$ : because $j$ goes from $i$ to $n$, then $j'$ goes from $0$ to $n-i$. And finally, you can get rid of the term $j'=0$ since it is zero !

Comment: thanks a lot, I actually thought j' would be read as j prime, indicating a derivative, but your answer makes total sense